# Binary of a number. How to check for equal series of digits?

Tags: c++, arrays, binary, digits

This is my code. What i want to do is to convert a number into his binary and if there is a series of equal digits to cout false else to cout true. For example, the number is 7 it's binary 111 it should cout false. But if the number is 10 its binary is 10000 which should be false, so my code cout true and I don't know where is my mistake.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void hasAlternatingBits(unsigned n) {
    int* a = new int[n];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; n > 0; i++)
    {
        a[i] = n % 2;
        n = n / 2;
    }
    /*for (i = i-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << a[i];
    }*/
    int arrSize = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        if (a[i] != a[i + 1]) {
            cout << "true";
        }
        else {
            cout << "false";
        }
    }
    delete[] a;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    hasAlternatingBits(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your problem in exact words, as "equal series of digits" is not clear, and both of your examples are... false?

Comment: Equal series of digits is 0,0 or 1,1. In the whole array, I should have at least 2 equal series like 10110  - here I should print false because I have 1,1. True is 101, 1, 0.

Comment: `new int[n]` is over allocating. For example 7 is `0b111`, its binary length is 3. Declare instead `new int[64]`. Next, `i` must be initialized to `0` and incremented. This will give you the count. Next, `sizeof(a)` is size of pointers. Count to `arraySize - 1` since you are asking for `[i + 1]`

Comment: Doesn't work again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with this code:

```
int* a = new int[n];
int i;
for (i = 0; n > 0; i++)
{
    a[i] = n % 2;
    n = n / 2;
}
```

Other than the fact that you over-allocate a, this is okay, I guess.

This, however, is just strange:

```
int arrSize = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
```

Here's what I would do. I'd make some variable name changes.

```
int arraySize;
for (arraySize = 0; n > 0; arraySize ++)
{
    a[arraySize] = n % 2;
    n = n / 2;
}
```

Then get rid of `int arrSize` entirely, as variable `arraySize` has exactly how many digits you stored in your array. Note that your version to calculate the arraySize is flawed.

Next, this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    if (a[i] != a[i + 1]) {
        cout << "true";
    }
    else {
        cout << "false";
    }
}
```

You're going to reference past the end of the variables you stored. What you could try is:

```
bool theyAllAlternate = true;
for (int i = 1; theyAllAlternate && i < arraySize; ++i) {
    if (a[i-1] == a[i]) {
        theyAllAlternate = false;
    }
}
```

Then output based on the value of `theyAllAlternate`. However, I don't actually understand if that's what you're really trying to do. Your code prints out a series of true/false, true/false based on whether the bits are flipping from one number to another -- but you go past the end of your bits.

I'm not sure that's what you're really after.

Note also: decimal 10 == binary 1010. (8 + 2).

Comment: I just want if a binary representation of some number has equal digits one after another to print false else to print true.